# What happen when auto increment column over its maximum in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use SQLite and its auto increment column. But I'm wondering what happen if the value reaches its maximum value(2,147,483,647 is the maximum value of 'long' type)
Anybody knows about it?

Comment: A long is 64 bits and can hold much larger values. You have other scaling problems before hitting that limit.

Comment: In this case insertion will throw you an error

Comment: @laalto: A long can be 64 bits, but it is not always 64 bits. That depends on the compiler / OS / CPU combination. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: @KağanKayal Yes in C. The question was Java and sqlite with more specific sizes for rowids and longs.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Without AUTOINCREMENT:

> If the largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of attempts, the insert operation fails with an SQLITE_FULL error.

With AUTOINCREMENT:

> If the table has previously held a row with the largest possible ROWID, then new INSERTs are not allowed and any attempt to insert a new row will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error.